# SQL JOIN each id in JSON object

Tags: sql, json, join, mariadb

I have a JSON column containing col_values for another table. I want to return rows from that other table for each item in the `JSON` object.

If this was an `INT` column, I would use `JOIN`, but I need to `JOIN` every entry in the `JSON` object.

## Take:

**`writers`** :

```sql
| id | name | projects (JSON)   |   
|:-- |:-----|:------------------|
| 1  | Andy | ["1","2","3","4"] |
| 2  | Hank | ["3","4","5","6"] |
| 3  | Alex | ["1","7","8","9"] |
| 4  | Joe  | ["1","5","6","7"] |
| 5  | Ken  | ["2","4","5","6"] |
| 6  | Zach | ["2","7","8","9"] |
| 7  | Walt | ["2","5","6","7"] |
| 8  | Mike | ["2","3","4","5"] |
```

**`cities`** :

```sql
| id | name     | project |
|:-- |:---------|:--------|
| 1  | Boston   | 1       |
| 2  | Chicago  | 2       |
| 3  | Cisco    | 3       |
| 4  | Seattle  | 4       |
| 5  | North    | 5       |
| 6  | West     | 6       |
| 7  | Miami    | 7       |
| 8  | York     | 8       |
| 9  | Tainan   | 9       |
| 10 | Seoul    | 1       |
| 11 | South    | 2       |
| 12 | Tokyo    | 3       |
| 13 | Carlisle | 4       |
| 14 | Fugging  | 5       |
| 15 | Turkey   | 6       |
| 16 | Paris    | 7       |
| 17 | Midguard | 8       |
| 18 | Fugging  | 9       |
| 19 | Madrid   | 1       |
| 20 | Salvador | 2       |
| 21 | Everett  | 3       |
```

I need every city ordered by `name` for Mike (`id`=`8`).

## Desired results:

This is what I'm getting and what I need to get (`ORDER BY name`).

**Output** :

```sql
| id | name     | project |
|:---|:---------|:--------|
| 13 | Carlisle | 4       |
| 2  | Chicago  | 2       |
| 3  | Cisco    | 3       |
| 21 | Everett  | 3       |
| 14 | Fugging  | 5       |
| 5  | North    | 5       |
| 20 | Salvador | 2       |
| 4  | Seattle  | 4       |
| 11 | South    | 2       |
| 12 | Tokyo    | 3       |
```

Current query, but this can't be the best way...

**SQL** >

```sql
SELECT c.* 
  FROM cities c 
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
      FROM writers w 
      WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(
        w.projects, CONCAT('\"', c.project, '\"')) 
      AND w.id = '8'
  ) 
 ORDER BY c.name;
```

**[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=dcf2a35f3f71f119ed58495a5c14f31e)** with the above. Is there a better way to do this "properly"?

---

**Background**

If it matters, I need to keep using `JSON` as the datatype because my server-side software that uses this database normally reads that column best if presented as a JSON object.

I would normally just do several database calls and iterate through that JSON object in my server-side language, but that is way too expensive with so many database calls, notwithstanding that it is even more costly to do multiple database calls for pagination.

I need all the results in a single database call. So, I need to `JOIN` or otherwise loop through each item in the JSON object within SQL.

Comment: Reviewers: I wanted to use normal SO table styling, but the system would not allow me to post this unless I wrapped the tables as blocks of code. Edit to your liking.

Comment: Which version of MariaDB?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your current query?

Comment: @mcalex `["1","2","3","4" ]` is valid JSON...

Comment: @mcalex My server side language thinks it is JSON because it can understand it as JSON.

Comment: I thought about using a comma-separated list in this col, but using valid JSON, however simple, was best so that other languages can understand it.

Comment: @Jesseיִשַׁי so anyway, what is the problem with your current query?

Comment: @Nick, it returns the known universe, not only the cols listed in my desired results.

Comment: If this doesn't get an answer soon, maybe I will create my own fiddle. Probably should do that anyway.

Comment: It works for me, although it should be more efficient to use a `JOIN` from `writers`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=18bd86bcae8de0ee5ad53f62629863b9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245378/discussion-between-jesse--and-nick).

Answer (score 0):

## Start with `JOIN`

Per a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72526684/sql-join-each-id-in-json-object#comment128119533_72526684) from [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/), there is a better way...

**SQL** >

```sql
SELECT c.*
  FROM writers w
  JOIN cities c ON JSON_CONTAINS(w.projects, CONCAT('\"', c.project, '\"'))
  WHERE w.id = '8'
  ORDER BY c.name;
```

Output is the same...

**Output** :

| id | name | project |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | Carlisle | 4 |
| 2 | Chicago | 2 |
| 3 | Cisco | 3 |
| 21 | Everett | 3 |
| 14 | Fugging | 5 |
| 5 | North | 5 |
| 20 | Salvador | 2 |
| 4 | Seattle | 4 |
| 11 | South | 2 |
| 12 | Tokyo | 3 |

**[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=f8188ec7749820b7cb414467e00a0137)**